# Xcode showing App uploaded Successfully .but it is not shown in itunesconnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Iam uploading an iPhone only application .iTunesConnect showing it requires iPad screenshots why??
Also,App uploaded to App store Successfully.But it is not shown in iTunesConnect.
My xCode version is 8.3.3
Thank you in Advance

Comment: Wait a few hours. They often just disappear after being uploaded, its very common.

Comment: definitely you will get a rejection mail. so wait for that

Answer (score 0):

Is this the first build of your app that you are uploading? If you have released a version with **Universal** target, you can't upload builds with **iPhone** only target anymore.

iPad screenshots are required only if your app is targeted Universal or iPad only. So make sure you have set Devices to iPhone in General tab.

Comment: Its the first build of my application.Also the device is set to iPhone.I just can't Figure out what is happening.Please help me.

Comment: Have you checked your email? Apple sends an email after rejecting and explains the reason they rejected your build.